# R - Problems creating dataframe from sapply results that combine lists

Tags: r, list, dataframe, sapply

I'm trying to create a dataframe from the results of sapply.

The variable fits is a collection of nls objects, all with the same names for coefficients. I am able to create a dataframe where the vectors are the coefficients and the rows are the individual fits using this:

```
Coefficients <- sapply(fits,function(x){coef(x)},simplify = TRUE,USE.NAMES = TRUE)
Coefficients_df <- data.frame(t(Coefficients))
```

This works fine and when I do summary(Coefficients_df), I get what I expect, the normal summary of a dataframe with 3 columns.

But what I want is to have a dataframe that includes the coefficients and the average error for each fit. I can get a matrix using this:

```
Coef_and_Error <- sapply(fits,function(x){c(coef(x),list(error = summary(x)$sigma))},simplify = TRUE,USE.NAMES = TRUE)
```

But then I do not get a proper dataframe using this:

```
Coef_and_Error_df <- data.frame(t(Coef_and_Error))
```

RStudio reports this as a dataframe (4105 obs. of 4 variables), but when I try to see a summary of the dataframe, it spews out a long list of "1  -none- numeric", flooding the console.

Also, when I click the triangle next to "Coef_and_Error_df"in Rstudio it does not show the sort of summary I'm used to. Instead of a simple summary with one row per column (e.g. k num 233 189 391 ...) It says "k: list of 4105"

I have been able to get the output I want by creating two separate matrices, converting both to dataframes and adding one as a new vector to the other, but that shouldn't be necessary.

I tried using "append" instead of "c" to combine the values, but no luck.

Comment: Change `c(coef(x),list(error = summary(x)$sigma))` to `c(coef(x), error = summary(x)$sigma)`.

Comment: `c(a_numeric_vector, a_list)` will return a list, you can check `apply(Coef_and_Error, 1, class)`. And that's why it prints out the summary of a list rather than the summary of a numeric vector.